# How to make sublists inherit item number

Tags: enumitem

I want sublists to inherit the number of the last item before the sublist in the list above it. I want to archive the same effect as shown in my minimal example, without hardcoding `1.` into the enumeration part of the sublist.

Can't find any macro in `enumitem`'s documentation that let me access the number. The usual solution by using `label*=` instead of `label=` doesn't work because I've `§` as part of the numbering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic* §]
    \item Item 1

    \begin{enumerate}[label=1.\arabic* §]
        \item Item 2
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: List with the result I want]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the value of the counter for an item in the outer list, use `\theenumi` (`i` stands for the first level of a list, **not** first item).

Now, the trick is to make use of `ref` option to change the format of that counter when printed as a reference.

In other words, `\theenumi` would print `1 §` (because of `label=\arabic* §`) and then the inner list would print `1 §.1 §` (because of `label=\theenumi.\arabic* §`), which is not what you want.

So, using the option `ref=\arabic*` in the first list makes the `\theenumi` equal to `1.1 §`, as desired.

[image]

Further reading: [5. Global settings](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) from user guide.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic* §, ref=\arabic*]
    \item Item 1\label{foo}

    \begin{enumerate}[label=\theenumi.\arabic* §, ref=\theenumi.\arabic*]
        \item Item 2\label{faa}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

In \ref{foo} we find \ref{faa}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm having some problem getting the numbering to work with two levels of sublists, I.e., with three layers of lists.

Comment: @inquisitiv3, the same idea, but with `\theenumii`

Comment: I love you! That solved it for me.

Comment: @inquisitiv3, check the user guide. You can create new list types so you don't need to use those options all the time you want such kind of list.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a slightly more general solution than [Sigur's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529208/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\prevlabel}{\csname theenum\romannumeral\numexpr\enit@depth-1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic* §,ref=\arabic*]
  \item Item 1

  \begin{enumerate}[label=\prevlabel.\arabic* §,ref=\prevlabel.\arabic*]
    \item Item 2

    \begin{enumerate}[label=\prevlabel.\arabic* §]
      \item Item 3
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

It picks up `\theenum<roman>` using the current `enumerate` depth (stored in `\enum@depth`).

Comment: I never read about `\enit@depth`.